# Issue with sarcasm detection

Tags: keras, nlp, data

I am working on the Reddit dataset for sarcasm detection but the sarcastic data points(1) are showing zero percent recall, precision, and accuracy however nonsarcastic are showing 100% recall and 50 precision. Below is the confusion matrix. I don't know why is it not showing any results on sarcastic class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More than precision/recall more concerning is the fact that all your data is being predicted as non-sarcastic. This seems like data cleanliness issue. You need to make sure your train/validation/test data is split and no overlap is present. Also make sure both the classes are present in all the 3 splits.